# How to get fix left side of table width and have the right side fill remaining width

Tags: html, css

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UR3HL/10/

```
<table cellspacing="3" border=1>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="100%">Heading</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="500" valign="top" align="center">Label One</td>
    <td width="100%" valign="top">Stuff about Label one. jkhsdf dhjsf hsdjkhfjk hjsd fhjskdfh jkdsh fjksdh fjdsh fjskdfh sdjkfh jsd fhjk
        <br>Reams and reams of text
        <br>etc.</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
    <td width="300" valign="top" align="center">A Longer Label Name</td>
    <td width="100%" valign="top">Stuff about Label two.
        <br>Reams and reams of text
        <br>etc.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the Label text to be non-wrapping. So the left half of the table will only be as wide as the longest label text all on one line. The right side would then fill the remaining space and its text would wrap lines.

Needs to work in IE and Chrome.

Comment: on which IE version? You can't say on IE like on Chrome. Chrome users in >95% have the latest version. With IE users there is not so simply.

Comment: If you want to block wrap just use css: `white-space:nowrap` for your left sides.. and works fine in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block wrap just use css:

```
white-space:nowrap
```

and if you like to get exact width your td like 500px you can use these css:

```
min-width:500px
```

or

```
width:500px
```

set it to your left side and test it.. and all of these css works fine in IE;)

Comment: Thanks; both work and will come in handy separately so appreciate stating all alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<table cellspacing="3" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="100%">Heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">Label One</td>
        <td valign="top">Stuff about Label one. jkhsdf dhjsf hsdjkhfjk hjsd fhjskdfh jkdsh fjksdh fjdsh fjskdfh sdjkfh jsd fhjk
            <br>Reams and reams of text
            <br>etc.</td>
    </tr>
                <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">A Longer Label Name</td>
        <td valign="top">Stuff about Label two.
            <br>Reams and reams of text
            <br>etc.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically remove your width styles, add the style of nowrap. Works on all browsers as seen here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp